# cannot connect to github via ssh

Tags: github, ssh, public-key

I have created keys and put my public key into my github account.
Then, in `~/.ssh` I created the following config file:

```
Host github
  HostName git@github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub
```

When I do ssh github

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git@github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

And when I do `ssh -T git@github.com`

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I doing wrong?
The public key I put in my github account says "Never used".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, you are trying to use the public key for authentication. The private key, is e.g. id_rsa2 while the public key is id_rsa2.pub, at least per default, when generated with ssh-keygen.

As default ssh uses id_rsa for identification, so you have to use:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2 -T git@github.com
```

The ssh config should look like this:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

The `Host` value is important, because that's what you have to use to use the configuration. You now can use `ssh github.com`. If you don't change the `Host` line, you need to use `ssh github`, but this could break other tools.

Alternatively you could use ssh-agent. In this case you do not need to create the config and just add the key to your ssh-agent and ssh to github.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
ssh -T git@github.com
```